# Order columns in dcast

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

How do I specify the column order, based on column 'Col' when using dcast?

```
df <- dcast(x, ID ~ ColumnName, value.var = "Answer")
```

I need the solution to be non specific to the data as x can be the results of any question (thus Col can be 1-3 or 1-2 etc.). Two dummy examples below of x.

```
ID        Answer        ColumnName        Col
1         Anduin        First Name        1
1         Wrynn         Surname           2
1         Alliance      Faction           3
2         Sylvanas      First Name        1
2         Windrunner    Surname           2
2         Horde         Faction           3



ID        Answer        ColumnName        Col
1         The Kirin Tor Quest             1
1         90            Level             2
2         Emissary      Quest             1
2         38            Level             2
```

Comment: Which order do you want to apply?

Answer (score 14):

It is not well documented, neither in `help("dcast", "reshape2")` nor in `help("dcast", "data.table")` but the columns are ordered by factor levels if `ColumnName` is a factor.

### Without `factor()`

The columns are ordered alphabetically which is not in line with the order specified in `Col`

```
reshape2::dcast(x, ID ~ ColumnName, value.var = "Answer")
```

> ```
>   ID  Faction First Name    Surname
> 1  1 Alliance     Anduin      Wrynn
> 2  2    Horde   Sylvanas Windrunner
> ```

### With factor levels ordered by appearance

Apparently, the OP is using `Col` to number `ColumnName` in order of appearance. Thus, `Col` is redundant and can be ignored.

There are several ways to create factor levels ordered by appearance directly in the formula of `dcast()`:

#### Base R

```
reshape2::dcast(x1, ID ~ factor(ColumnName, levels = unique(ColumnName)), value.var = "Answer")
```

> ```
>   ID First Name    Surname  Faction
> 1  1     Anduin      Wrynn Alliance
> 2  2   Sylvanas Windrunner    Horde
> ```

```
reshape2::dcast(x2, ID ~ factor(ColumnName, levels = unique(ColumnName)), value.var = "Answer")
```

> ```
>   ID         Quest Level
> 1  1 The Kirin Tor    90
> 2  2      Emissary    38
> ```

As requested by the OP, the solution is non specific to the data.

#### `forcats`

The `forcats` package has some handy functions to deal with factors. `as_factor()` creates levels in the order in which they appear:

```
reshape2::dcast(x1, ID ~ forcats::as_factor(ColumnName), value.var = "Answer")
```

(The result is the same as above.)

To make the code more explicit, `fct_inorder()` can be used:

```
reshape2::dcast(x1, ID ~ forcats::fct_inorder(ColumnName), value.var = "Answer")
```

### With factor levels ordered by `Col`

In case the requested column order is different from the order of appearance, the columns can be ordered by factor levels which are derived from `Col`. For demonstration, a modified sample dataset is used.

With base R,

```
reshape2::dcast(x3, ID ~ reorder(factor(ColumnName), Col), value.var = "Answer")
```

> ```
>   ID    Surname  Faction First Name
> 1  1      Wrynn Alliance     Anduin
> 2  2 Windrunner    Horde   Sylvanas
> ```

or with `forcats`

```
reshape2::dcast(x3, ID ~ forcats::fct_reorder(ColumnName, Col), value.var = "Answer")
```

### Data

```
x1 <- readr::read_table(
"ID        Answer        ColumnName        Col
1         Anduin        First Name        1
1         Wrynn         Surname           2
1         Alliance      Faction           3
2         Sylvanas      First Name        1
2         Windrunner    Surname           2
2         Horde         Faction           3")

x2 <- data.table::fread(
'ID        Answer           ColumnName        Col 
1         "The Kirin Tor"  Quest             1 
1         90               Level             2 
2         Emissary         Quest             1 
2         38               Level             2')
```

Modified sample dataset with a given column order (other than order of appearance or alphabetically order):

```
x3 <- readr::read_table(
"ID        Answer        ColumnName        Col
1         Anduin        First Name        3
1         Wrynn         Surname           1
1         Alliance      Faction           2
2         Sylvanas      First Name        3
2         Windrunner    Surname           1
2         Horde         Faction           2")
```

Comment: great! thanks for the help, useful until now. I'm wondering how do you found out that columns are ordered by factor levels?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing a `dcast` argument that allows to specify the final order of columns but it is always possible to subset the result.

```
fun_dcast <- function(DF, formula = ID ~ ColumnName, value.var = "Answer"){
  reshape2::dcast(DF, formula, value.var = value.var)[c(1, 1 + unique(DF[["Col"]]))]
}

fun_dcast(x1)
#  ID  Faction First Name    Surname
#1  1 Alliance     Anduin      Wrynn
#2  2    Horde   Sylvanas Windrunner

fun_dcast(x2)
#  ID Level         Quest
#1  1    90 The Kirin Tor
#2  2    38      Emissary
```

**Data.**

```
x1 <- read.table(text = "
ID        Answer        ColumnName        Col
1         Anduin        'First Name'        1
1         Wrynn         Surname           2
1         Alliance      Faction           3
2         Sylvanas      'First Name'        1
2         Windrunner    Surname           2
2         Horde         Faction           3
", header = TRUE)


x2 <- read.table(text = "
ID        Answer        ColumnName        Col
1         'The Kirin Tor' Quest             1
1         90            Level             2
2         Emissary      Quest             1
2         38            Level             2
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient, but I think the following solution is simple.  It does require you to provide a vector of all possible column names that might be encountered, though (i.e. `desiredOrder`).

```
thisdf <- data.frame(c3 = c("milk", "cheese", "toast", "gravy","spice"),
                      c2 = c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26),
                      c1 = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
)
desiredOrder <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4")
colsPresent <- desiredOrder[desiredOrder %in% names(thisdf)]
thisdf<-thisdf[,colsPresent]
```